# Change BackendAppressPool on Azure Load Balancer Rule using Powershell AZ

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to change the backend address pool on a pre-existing Load Balancer rule.

I have looked into using *Set-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig* but it would appear I need to provide all the information for the rule to be rebuilt... ie: the FrontendIpConfiguration, Protocol, FrontendPort, BackendPort, and Probe, as well at the new BackendAddressPool to be used:

```
ForEach($Rule in $BAPFrom.LoadBalancingRules){

$LbRule = $slb.LoadBalancingRules | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $Rule.Id}

$slb | Set-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name $LbRule.Name `
            -FrontendIPConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] `
            -Protocol $LbRule.Protocol `
            -FrontendPort $LbRule.FrontendPort `
            -BackendPort $LbRule.BackendPort `
            -BackendAddressPool $BAP #`
            #-Probe $LbRule.Probe}
```

Is there not a way to just change the BackendAddressPool on a pre-existing rule, without needing to pass in each of these parameters again?

Comment: May I know if you have tried `Set-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPool`.Please refer this for more details : [Set-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPool (Az.Network) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-azloadbalancerbackendaddresspool?view=azps-6.6.0)

Comment: I don't believe this is suitable, as the second backend address pool already exists, I just need to switch a certain batch of rules over from the first backend address pool to the second.

Comment: then i don't think that will be possible as updating the load balancer  rule needs all the parameters.

Comment: let me run some tests and  confirm it for you ..

Comment: Thanks.
I guess essentially what I want to do is this:

$slb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name "LB-1" -ResourceGroupName "LbTest";

$MyBackendPool2 = $slb | Get-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPool -Name 'pool-ext-b';

Get-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name 'rule-int-6464' | Set-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -BackendAddressPool $MyBackendPool2;

So that it just switches the existing rule to use a different existing backend pool, but like you say, it requires all of the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Comments , The process which you are trying to implement is not possible .

**I tested the same in my environment:**

**Scenario:** 1 load balancer , 1 load balancing rule and 2 backend pools.

[image]

My default Pool in the rule is `loadbalancerbackendpool` as you can see below:

[image]

I tried to change it to the second pool i.e. `Loadbalancerbackenpooloutbound`.It was successful but if you see the output only the backendpool id is correct and others have been changed to default and are not same as my previous rule as shown below.

[image]

**Solution:** The only solution available is that you get the rule config which you want to update and while updating the rule provide the parameters collected from the get rule operation, something like below:

```
$slb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name "ansumantest-lb" -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup"
$MyBackendPool2 = $slb | Get-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPool -Name 'LoadBalancerBackEndPoolOutbound'
$rule=Get-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name 'myHTTPRule'
$slb|Set-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name $rule.Name -BackendAddressPool $MyBackendPool2 -Protocol $rule.Protocol -FrontendPort $rule.FrontendPort -BackendPort $rule.BackendPort
```